# NSTimer приостанавливает выполнение при скролле uitableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Есть UIVew c кнопкой старт,  UILabel  в который записывается текущее время и uitableView, в котором время сохраняется (как простой стандартный таймер)

Проблема в том, что при скролле таблицы - таймер замерзает, как сделать чтобы они работали синхронно ?

имею такой таймер

```
- (IBAction)startTimer {
    _startButton.hidden = YES;
    _stopButton.hidden = NO;

    isRun = YES;

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    }];

    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01f
                                               target:self
                                             selector:@selector(tick)
                                             userInfo:nil
                                              repeats:YES];

}
```

и функию

```
- (void)tick {

    _timeSot++;

    sot++;

    if (_timeSot > 99) {
        _timeSot = 0;
        _sec++;
    }
    if (_sec > 59) {
        _sec = 0;
        _min++;
    }
    //_min = _sec / 60;

    NSString *sotStr;
    if (_timeSot < 10) {
        sotStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", _timeSot];
    } else {
        sotStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _timeSot];
    }

    NSString *secStr;
    if (_sec < 10) {
        secStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", _sec];
    } else {
        secStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _sec];
    }

    NSString *minStr;
    if (_min < 10) {
        minStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", _min];
    } else {
        minStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _min];
    }

    myTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@:%@", minStr, secStr, sotStr];

    if (sot >= ([[[_exerises objectAtIndex:_indexExercise] objectForKey:@"timeWorkOutExerciseClient"] intValue] * 100)) {
        [self stopTimer];
        [self sendNotification];
    }

    [_timeLabel setText:myTime];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема решена:

```
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```